# set xlabel matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I've got a matplotlib question that I want to ask.

In the below image I want to 'enlarge' the label, instead of having a range(0,1,0.2), I want a range(0,1,0.01) and visualize every step(0.01, 0.02, 0.03, ...).

This is my plot code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6),dpi=800)
count = (frecuency/len(acousticness))
width = 0.005
print(type(frequency))    

ax.set_ylim([0, 3])
xlim=np.arange(0,1,0.01)
my_colors = 'rgbkymc'
plt.bar(frecuency.index, frecuency,width,edgecolor="Orange",color=my_colors)
plt.ylim(0, 5)
plt.xlim(xlim)
# Add labels
plt.title('Histogram of Acousticness')
plt.xlabel('Acousticness')
plt.ylabel('Frecuency')
```

Also, an error ocurred on `plt.xlim(xlim)`:

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

[image]

Comment: `xlim` is `x limits`. That's not what you're looking for, try [xticks](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html).

Comment: frequency spelling mistake

Comment: As sarema and BigBen told me, what I want to modify are the Xticks and not the xlimits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xlim=np.arange(0,1,0.01)
plt.xlim(xlim)
```

You are calling the wrong method. You probably want to change the second line to

```
plt.xticks(xlim)
```

to make it work. (Then it is a good idea to change the variable name as well.)